# The ask of Date method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I write the following code

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    class Date extends React.Component{
        dataToString = (d) =>{
        return [
        d.getFullYear(),
        d.getMonth + 1,
        d.getDate()
      ].join('-')
    }
```

Error as shown below，thanks everyone。

```
Uncaught TypeError: d.getFullYear is not a function
at Date._this.dataToString (index.js:10)
at Date.render (index.js:18)
at ReactCompositeComponent.js:796
at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
at
```

Online, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right way writing `React Component`.

Issue is: Whenever we use any `React.Component`, we have to define a `render` method. That is the `starting` point for that `component`, means this is the place from where React starts the `UI creation`, and you didn't define the `render` method.

If you just want to write a file that contains only some `generic methods`, create it like this:

```
module.exports{

    dataToString : function(d){
        return [
        d.getFullYear(),
        d.getMonth() + 1,
        d.getDate()
      ].join('-');
   },

   dateOnly: function(d){
       /*write your logic here*/
       return d;
   }      

}
```

You can use these methods by `importing` this file anywhere in the project.

Or if you want to write it like it as a `component`, then define the `render` method also, like this:

```
class DateClass extends React.Component{
        dataToString(d) {
           return [
              d.getFullYear(),
              d.getMonth() + 1,
              d.getDate()
           ].join('-')
         }

         render(){
            return <div>{this.dataToString(new Date())}</div>
         }
 }
```

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Thank you very much,My error id Date ,I should user DateClass<br>class DateClass extends React.Component{